# update transaction stuck from last few days in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, database-deadlocks

update transaction is stuck from last few days in postgres 9.2. Select on pg_locks shows one ShareLock granted is false. I have not added any explicit locks around my script. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction must be waiting on a lock that is held by another open transaction that is either *active* or *idle in transaction*.

Terminate that transaction and the hanging transaction will be able to proceed.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz for your response. That is what is happening. Can we add some explicit lock to handle this situation? How to find which transaction is not releasing the lock?

Comment: You could try one of the queries from [the Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_dependency_information).